# How to format export fields with numeric values in django-import-export

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-import-export

Using `django-import-export` to export data from django admin in excel xlsx format.

However, numeric fields export as text in excel.

[image]

I'd like to export correctly as numeric fields.

[Documentation](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_widgets.html) has a sample syntax for `BooleanWidget`, but it's not working, it replaces the value with the object __str__ value, instead of converting the value to a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out I have to instantiate the widget, not reference the class (Use parenthesis at the end)

```
from import_export import widgets

enrolled = fields.Field(widget=widgets.NumberWidget())`
```

Created a [pull request](https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export/pull/1193) to fix sample usage.